# Saving the page avoids the security

Tags: orangedox

I'm testing the service. I uploaded a PDF document that I don't want to be downloaded or printed. The document is at https://dl.orangedox.com/test.doc with password 12345
It works fine inside the browser, but if I go to File->Save page, the browser downloads all the content and the user can view and print the content (because the document is saved as images).

Is there any more secure option or simply doing this people can avoid you secure service?

Answer (score 0):

You can save any webpage on the internet including a document preview page on Orangedox.  Though keep in mind that only the parts of the document will be viewable when downloaded.  Also printing directly from Orangedox, or from a saved page, is not supported by the browser.

As for "avoiding security" your document is still protected by a password and can only be accessed by those you've given your password to. Always make sure you're sharing your documents with those you trust and keep in mind that anyone can always screenshot the pages of your document.